# Transforming input string: Unlist?

Tags: pandas, list, transform

I have following example DataFrame that I like to transform:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
d = {'example' : pd.Series(["['Adventure' 'African elephant' 'Animal' 'Ball game' 'Bay' 'Body of water' 'Communication Device' 'Electronic device']"])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.example = [[w.replace(' ', '_') for w in re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", x.lower())] for x in tqdm(df.example)]
df
```

**Out:**

> 0 [adventure, african_elephant, animal, ball_game ...]

The transformation (and data input) itself is correct, however, how can I transform each row in the DataFrame so that each row is not a list, but a simple string of tokens?

**Desired output:**

Out:

> 0 adventure, african_elephant, animal, ball_game ...

*I tried:*

```
df.example = [(w.replace(' ', '_') for w in re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", x.lower())) for x in tqdm(df.example)]
```

However, this returned `<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x11...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only add `join` to generator:

```
df.example = [', '.join(w.replace(' ', '_') for w in re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", x.lower()))
              for x in (df.example)]

print (df)
                                             example
0  adventure, african_elephant, animal, ball_game...
```

Comment: I checked my data and apparently, it created a lot of those: `_, _, _, _, _, _, _, `...

Comment: @Christopher - also with sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, maybe pandas str.join will be useful for the future ;-) 
1) added second row to your exemplary dataframe 
2) did not modify your generator 
3) added an extra line:

```
    df['example'] = df['example'].str.join(',')
```

Working examaple:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
d = {
    'example' : pd.Series([
        "['a' 'b c' 'd' 'e f' 'g' 'h i j' 'k l' 'm n']",
        "['a' 'b c' 'd']"
    ]),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
display(df)
    example
0   ['a' 'b c' 'd' 'e f' 'g' 'h i j' 'k l' 'm n']
1   ['a' 'b c' 'd']

df.example = [[w.replace(' ', '_') for w in re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", x.lower())] for x in tqdm(df.example)]
df['example'] = df['example'].str.join(',')
display(df)
    example
0   a,b_c,d,e_f,g,h_i_j,k_l,m_n
1   a,b_c,d
```